# How can i use blowfish encryption/decryption in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, cryptography

Is there a way i can implement blowfish crypt in vb.net project? i looked everywher but couldn't find anything in `System.Security.Cryptography` or microsoft's vb.net documentations regarding this type of encryption! please help, if it's not supported natively does anyone knows a good 3rd party library?

Comment: Why do you want to use blowfish instead of a newer cipher? 64 bit block ciphers are annoying to use since you need to rotate keys after encrypting a few GB.

Comment: Do you really need to *implement* Blowfish in VB.NET project, or just to *use* Blowfish from VB.NET- or any other .NET-application? If the latter, then why wouldn't you try BouncyCastle? If the former, then I have an implementation exactly in VB.NET, but half of its core module is just a huge array of initialization constants, and it additionally requires 2 wrapper modules to act as `SymmetricAlgorithm` and `ICryptoTransform` — pretty much for StackOverflow.

Comment: @CodesInChaos i'm dealing with an old server that requires this type of cipher

Comment: @AntonSamsonov i'm not sure what you mean but i just need to encrypt/decrypt data between the application and the server

Comment: @razzak If you don't need to keep your project self-contained and don't mind adding other projects (in C#) to your solution, then you definitely should to give [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/) a try with its `Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Engines.BlowfishEngine` and appropriate wrappers to suit your data-processing style.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Bob Learned (TheLearnedOne)** for the [Reference](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/Q_22915568.html#accepted-solution)

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports BlowFish.BlowfishNET
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ShowBlowfishAlgorithm()
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim buf As Byte() = New Byte(2) {}
        Dim encData As Byte(), decData As Byte()
        ' set up the algorithm (set to false to go with AES for comparison purposes) 
        Dim alg As SymmetricAlgorithm = MakeAlgo(True)
        ' we encrypt and decrypt from and to a memory stream, so first we have to set up a 
        ' source (by writing some bytes to it) and a target stream 
        Dim inStream As New MemoryStream()
        For i = 0 To 10
            inStream.WriteByte(CByte(i))
        Next
        inStream.Position = 0
        ' need to reset it for the following reading 
        Dim outStream As New MemoryStream()

        ' now we create a crypto stream, to show that our BlowfishAlgorithm plays together 
        ' with a standard .NET framework security component 
        Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(outStream, alg.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        ' write data from our input stream to the encrypted stream (which then will finally 
        ' put it into our output stream) by using a small buffer (as it it is done usually) 
        While inStream.Position < inStream.Length
            Dim read As Integer = inStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)
            encStream.Write(buf, 0, read)
        End While
        encStream.Close()
        ' show what we got for the encrypted data 
        encData = outStream.ToArray()
        Console.WriteLine("plain : " + HexPrint(inStream.ToArray()))
        Console.WriteLine("encrypted: " + HexPrint(encData))
        ' decrypt the encrypted data, with the an input stream now set up with the 
        ' encrypted data and being passed to the decryption stream 
        outStream = New MemoryStream()
        Dim decStream As New CryptoStream(New MemoryStream(encData), alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read)
        While outStream.Position < encData.Length
            Dim read As Integer = decStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)
            If 0 = read Then
                Exit While
            End If
            outStream.Write(buf, 0, read)
        End While
        decStream.Close()
        decData = outStream.ToArray()
        Console.WriteLine("decrypted: " + HexPrint(decData))
        For i = 0 To 10
            ' verify that we got the right data back by simulating and comparing the 
            ' original input data 
            If decData(i) <> i Then
                Console.WriteLine("decryption error!")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Function HexPrint(ByVal buf As Byte()) As String
        Dim result As New StringBuilder(buf.Length * 3)

        For i As Integer = 0 To buf.Length - 1
            If i > 0 Then
                result.Append(" "c)
            End If
            result.Append(buf(i).ToString("x2"))
        Next i
        Return result.ToString()
    End Function

    Private Function MakeAlgo(ByVal useBlowfish As Boolean) As SymmetricAlgorithm
        Dim result As SymmetricAlgorithm = IIf((useBlowfish), New BlowfishAlgorithm(), SymmetricAlgorithm.Create())
        result.Mode = CipherMode.CBC
        If useBlowfish Then
            result.KeySize = 40
        End If
        result.GenerateKey()
        result.GenerateIV()
        result.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Pretty bad example. 1) You didn't include a link to the required third party library 2) Unnecessarily complicated, all those streams when there is a simple `TransformFinalBlock` call. 3) Doesn't include proper IV handling 4) Doesn't specify the mode of operation explicitly